# Bash: how to count files in subfolders efficiently on remote NFS drive?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, nfs

I'm trying to batch an operation that counts files in a given subfolder of a remote NFS drive.

The NFS client is Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.
I have very few informations on the remote NFS server.
It's an NFS v3. It's anonimously rw mounted and its authentication is IP based.  The bandwidth of the client is a 100/10 and it can upload around 1.1 MB/s. The provider advertises its backup storage to be 1Gbit/1Gbit guranteed. The usable size of the volume is <4TB, the expected count of files is estimated in >600000 units.

--**Edit #1**:

### The storage's advertised guaranteed IOPs is 2000 but testing the remote fs results in 7-800iops.

The mount options used on the client are as suggested by the provider:

```
rsize=8192,wsize=8192,timeo=14,intr
```

To perform the count, my choice was this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
if [[ $# -eq 0 ]] ; then
   echo 'no folder supplied, use $0 /path/to/folder'
   exit 0
else
   COUNT=$(find $1 -type f|wc -l)
   echo $1 contains $COUNT files.
fi
exit 0
```

I tried it on my home, and it was obviously very fast, outputting:

```
/home/user contains 12 files.
```

When I try to get such stat from the remote NFS drive, the script sits down "forever".

**--Edit #2:**

**I tried removing the `|wc -l` and add `>> $LOGFILE` at the end of the `find`, but it looks like it randomly hangs in a 2 to 24 hours time range and when it hangs after long time, the list is far from beeing complete.**

I tought I could split the find in chunks, in order to prevent this issue, maybe producing a list of all subfolders...

```
for d in $FOLDERLIST;
do
   find $d -maxdepth 0 -type f|wc -l >> $TMPLOG
done
```

..and then sum all the numbers in $TMPLOG, so maybe in smaller operations the script won't hang.

**QUESTION: Am I using the best possible resource saving way to perform this count? Maybe there's a cheaper way than `find` to get files count?**

I'm considering it maybe the wrong approach to count files, since I saw how long it takes on the remote drive there should be quite an overhead... I remember when I had some experience on remote filesystems mounted via curlftpfs. Huge overhead, huge delay.

NFS should be much better about that, but in this case it doesn't seems!

Comment: As the scripts hangs after a few hours, i'd split it in chunks. I know it hangs because i tried to remove the |wc -l part and pipe the output to a local file. between 2 and 24 hours this very long find will hang, and stop populating the list. After 24 hours, the list was far to be complete, there were no duplicates, there are no chances files are beeing counted two times. The possible for was a workaround for the hanging long find.

Comment: The question is: what is the best way to count files on a remote slow filesystem. Maybe find . -type f |wc -l is not?

Comment: I'm voting to move this question to [unix.se] since it's more about how unix works than about systems administration. There are some brilliant people there who know a lot more about file systems and unix than most of us here.

Comment: @JennyD I actually had this doubt, I decided to post here because I still don't know if it's an NFS client/server issue or a wrong unix commands utilization. In the first case, this would be the place, in the second one Unix & Linux. Do you agree?

Comment: In the first case, this would be one of the suitable places, U&L being the other. There are a number of questions that are on-topic in both places - and since you've not gotten any answers here in two days, I think that moving it will give you a better chance of help. (That's the only reason for moving it, by the way: not because you were wrong to post here.)

Comment: I don't have a ready answer for you, but I think you'd be well served by determining *for a fact* whether the issue is the listing and counting of files, or if there is a problem with the NFS link (client, connectivity or server). If it's the NFS side of things that is causing you grief, then this question might be better served by remaining here than on [unix.se], but if so, you should re-focus it considerably.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with `rsync`, using something similar to:

```
rsync --stats -na <srcdir> /tmp/fakedir
```

The first two line of the output will be like this:

```
Number of files: 2000
Number of files transferred: 1900
```

The first value is the sum of dirs+files entries, while **the second one is number of files only**

Comment: I still don't know if that's actually the fastest and cheapest way, but it worked 5 times in a row without ant of the issues that I used to experience with find.